# RangeError: length > kMaxLength while reading massive text file with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a huge(~1.5 gig) text file to read with 'fs' and it gives me back this error:

```
RangeError
RangeError: length > kMaxLength
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:242:21)
    at fs.js:130:16
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
```

Here is part of my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('file.txt', 'ASCII', function (err, data) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

It gets me back error even though i use this command: node --max-old-space-size=8000 file.js
Any suggestions are welcome:) 
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even for a 64-bit install, you can't increase the memory limit beyond ~1.7GB (~1GB for 32-bit).  See the [FAQ](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/FAQ).  So you can't set `--max-old-space-size` beyond that limit.

Can you use a [streaming read](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) interface to the file instead?

Comment: this faq line is outdated and does not apply to node.js that is using V8 3.7 or newer. The error in question is the limitation on the maximum length of the string that has nothing to do with the memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

As JohnnyHK mentioned, [using streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) is the right solution. Use [fs.createReadStream](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) to create streams from the file system:

```
fs.createReadStream('file.txt', {encoding: 'ASCII'}).pipe(process.stdout)
```